# Matrix multiplication with threads and semaphore

Tags: multithreading, matrix

I have to implement matrix multiplication with threads using semaphore. The problem is I don't understand how semaphore works and my result matrix is filled with zeros and program hangs. Could you explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
class Program
{
    private static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0, 1);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int size;
        int[,] a = null, b = null, c = null;
        bool isNumeric;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Insert size: ");
            isNumeric = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out size);
        }
        while (!isNumeric || size < 2);
        Console.WriteLine();
        SquareMatrix.Init(size, ref a);
        SquareMatrix.Init(size, ref b);
        SquareMatrix.Init(size, ref c);
        SquareMatrix.Fill(a);
        SquareMatrix.Fill(b);
        Console.WriteLine("Matrix 1:\n");
        SquareMatrix.Display(a);
        Console.WriteLine("Matrix 2:\n");
        SquareMatrix.Display(b);
        Console.WriteLine();
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => Multiply(i, size, a, b, c));
            thread.Name = i.ToString();
            thread.Start();
        }
        DateTime stop = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Result (" + (stop - start).TotalMilliseconds + " ms):\n");
        SquareMatrix.Display(c);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void Multiply(int i, int size, int[,] a, int[,] b, int[,] c)
    {
        semaphore.WaitOne();
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            c[i, j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
            {
                c[i, j] += a[i, k] * b[k, j];
            }
        }
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

And SquareMatrix code:

```
static class SquareMatrix
{
    private static readonly Random random = new Random();
    public static void Init(int size, ref int[,] array)
    {
        array = new int[size, size];
    }
    public static void Fill(int[,] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(0); j++)
            {

                array[i, j] = random.Next(-10, 10);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Display(int[,] array)
    {
        string result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(0); j++)
                result += array[i, j] + " ";
            result += "\n";
        }
        Console.Write(result + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could reduce this program to two lines.

Comment: If you don't want to help me, just don't comment.

Comment: I'm pointing out the site rules and the reason why nobody else seems to want to help you. Also, by reducing the code you likely can identify the bug yourself. Trying to help you here.